# why am i getting error CS0246 in .net core 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I created a project in dot-net core 3.0.100. but i got mysterious error while try to run the project, this occurred after i installed few packages which listed bellow.

```
- > Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core               5.2.7       5.2.7
- > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc                   2.2.0       2.2.0
- > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language        2.2.0       2.2.0
- > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore              3.1.0       3.1.0
- > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design       3.1.0       3.1.0
- > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools        3.1.0       3.1.0
- > Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL      3.1.0       3.1.0
- > Swashbuckle.AspNetCore                     5.0.0-rc4   5.0.0-rc4
```

**ERROR MESSAE IN DETIL**

```
[![D:\AngularAdmin-panel\API\API.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
D:\AngularAdmin-panel\API\API.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\build\netstandard2.0\Sdk.Razor.CurrentVersion.targets(404,5): warning RAZORSDK1006: Detected Razor language version downgrade. This is typically caused by a reference to the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design package. Consider removing this package reference. \[D:\AngularAdmin-panel\API\API.csproj\]
CSC : warning CS8034: Unable to load Analyzer assembly C:\Users\DEV4\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.analyzers\2.2.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers.dll : Assembly with same name is already loaded \[D:\AngularAdmin-panel\API\API.csproj\]
Startup.cs(29,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IConfigurtion' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) \[D:\AngularAdmin-panel\API\API.csproj\]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.][1]][1]
```

Comment: Please file complete demo solution from the link bellow. thanks in advance. https://github.com/sanshanthan/DashBoard-API

Comment: `IConfigurtion` seems like a typo. Did you mean `IConfiguration`?

Comment: @Métoule yeah.. thanks, but in coding i couldn't find IConfigurtion,even in Startup.cs following lines are exists.                                                            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }